# How should i store api call data for a webserver

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm building a Flask web application. I use an API to retrieve data once per day. The data is returned as JSON. The JSON is stored in a file, and is sent to the client each time they access the site. The application uses an SQLite database to keep track of user information and user-associated data.

How should I go about storing the data received from the API? Would it be preferable to store it in the database since it is just updated once per day, or should I keep the response in a JSON format as I do currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question you are asking is **how should I store data**. It doesn't matter, nor does anybody care, where the data originates from: a message queue, an HTTP request, from the code itself. Here are the parameters for your problem:

1. You have data.
2. You want to know the best way to store the data.
3. You are currently using a SQLite database for user information and associated data
4. For this new data, you are currently storing it in a JSON file

Next you have to ask yourself the following questions:

1. How much data are you storing?
2. Is the data structured?
3. Will I be querying the data by a specific field?
4. Does the user need every part of the JSON file?
5. How often will the data be requested?

I made a little flowchart to help you out:

[image: Flowchart of whether or not to use a database or a file]